# How do i solve '"Reference to type 'BaseControlContext" claim.....' for AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server

Tags: oauth, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openid-connect, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am facing weird issue.
I am reading and creating `OpenID Connect server with ASOS` this article [ASOS - AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server](http://kevinchalet.com/2016/07/13/creating-your-own-openid-connect-server-with-asos-creating-your-own-authorization-provider/).

I simply created new sample solution and added new subclass `AuthorizationProvider` class of OpenIdConnectServerProvider and override the virtual method `i.e. ExtractAuthorizationRequest`

**AuthorizationProvider.cs**

```
public class AuthorizationProvider : OpenIdConnectServerProvider
{
    public override Task ExtractAuthorizationRequest(ExtractAuthorizationRequestContext context)
    {
        // If a request_id parameter can be found in the authorization request,
        // restore the complete authorization request stored in the user session.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.RequestId))
        {
            var payload = context.HttpContext.Session.Get(context.Request.RequestId);
            if (payload == null)
            {
                context.Reject(
                    error: OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidRequest,
                    description: "Invalid request: timeout expired.");
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
            // Restore the authorization request parameters from the serialized payload.
            using (var reader = new BsonReader(new MemoryStream(payload)))
            {
                foreach (var parameter in JObject.Load(reader))
                {
                    // Avoid overriding the current request parameters.
                    if (context.Request.HasParameter(parameter.Key))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    context.Request.SetParameter(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
                }
            }
        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

**Issue**:
As soon as i add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity (2.0.0)` NuGet package to my project, `context.Reject` start giving the following error

> "Reference to type 'BaseControlContext" claim it is defined in
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, but it could not be found.

But as soon as I remove `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` NuGet dependency, the error goes away and all looks fine.

**Note:**

2. I am using VS 2017.
3. I am using dotnetcore 2.0 SDK.
4. I created solution using .Net Core 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

Massive changes have been introduced in ASP.NET Core 2.0's authentication stack. The changes are so important that all the authentication middleware written for ASP.NET Core 1.x are not compatible (which includes all the aspnet-contrib projects).

You can read https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/262 for more information.

The good news is that we have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 RTM-compatible version of ASOS. You can find the `2.0.0-preview1-*` bits on the aspnet-contrib MyGet feed (https://www.myget.org/F/aspnet-contrib/api/v3/index.json).

Comment: Thanks for your comments

Comment: Does this also mean i can not implement IAppBuilder in IApplicationBuilder using UseOwin method as per microsoft official guideline? Can you have a look at this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847623/unable-to-configuer-iapplicationbuilder-useowin

Comment: @immirza I'm not sure I understand your question. ASOS for ASP.NET Core (1.x or 2.x) doesn't depend on OWIN, so you don't need an adapter to make it work (it's a native ASP.NET Core component).

Comment: yes thats true and i understand. "ASOS for ASP.NET Core (1.x or 2.x) doesn't depend on OWIN". I asked something different. Did you have a change to look at the question link?