# Unable to configure 'IApplicationBuilder UseOwin'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, owin

As stated in official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/owin), I am trying to implement `UseOwin` in the `Startup.cs.`I am trying to use/port `IAppBuilder (Microsoft.Owin.Builder.AppBuilder)` inside `IApplicationBuilder (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder)`. I had legacy code written using `IAppBuilder` running fine on .Net Framework 4.5.

I have seen couple of examples about using IAppBuilder in IAplicationBuilder e.g. [example 1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1122162/Implement-Owin-Pipeline-using-Asp-net-Core) [example 2](https://github.com/tusdotnet/tusdotnet/wiki/Troubleshoot:-%22'IApplicationBuilder'-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-'UseTus'%22-in-ASP.NET-Core). These attempts were about .netcore 1.1 and not .net core 2.0. May be this is the reason i am unable to port.

Please share your thoughts whether i am trying to achieve something not possible at the moment in .net core 2.0 or there is some error in my code.

Note:
I am using `dotnetcore 2.0` with `Visual Studio 2017`

**Error**

I am getting following error.

> return owinAppBuilder.Build,
>   Task>>(); TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'System.Security.Cryptography.DpapiDataProtector' from assembly
>   'System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

**My attempt**

```
    app.UseOwin(setup => setup(next =>
    {
        var owinAppBuilder = new AppBuilder();

        var aspNetCoreLifetime =
            (IApplicationLifetime)app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IApplicationLifetime));

        new AppProperties(owinAppBuilder.Properties)
        {
            OnAppDisposing = aspNetCoreLifetime?.ApplicationStopping ?? CancellationToken.None,
            DefaultApp = next,
            AppName = "test"
        };

        // Only required if CORS is used, configure it as you wish
        var corsPolicy = new System.Web.Cors.CorsPolicy
        {

            AllowAnyHeader = true,
            AllowAnyMethod = true,
            AllowAnyOrigin = true,
            SupportsCredentials = true
        };

        //corsPolicy.GetType()
        //      .GetProperty(nameof(corsPolicy.ExposedHeaders))
        //      .SetValue(corsPolicy, tusdotnet.Helpers.CorsHelper.GetExposedHeaders());

        owinAppBuilder.UseCors(new Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions
        {
            PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
            {
                PolicyResolver = context => Task.FromResult(corsPolicy)
            }
        });

        PublicClientId = "self";

        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/Login"),
            Provider = new MyServiceProvider(PublicClientId),

            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            RefreshTokenProvider = new MyRefreshTokenProvider(),
        };

        owinAppBuilder.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
        //owinAppBuilder.UseTus(context => new DefaultTusConfiguration
        //{
        //    // Excluded for brevity, use the same configuration as you would normally do
        //});


        return owinAppBuilder.Build<Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>>();
    }));
```

Comment: Same thing here, have you managed to find a solution? I require OWIN for SignalR myself/

Answer (score 2):

`Microsoft.Owin` and related packages do not have targets for .NET Core, no for .NET Standard. All they have is dlls targeting full .NET. You can reference such libraries from your project targeting .NET Core, but they are not guaranteed to work, as you see yourself, because API (set of classes\methods\signatures) of full .NET and .NET Core are different. Visual Studio even will show a warning when you are doing that, for example:

> Package 'Microsoft.Owin 3.1.0' was restored using
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.

There is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin` package and you can use OWIN middleware in .NET Core app as your first link describes, but almost all it provides is `UseOwin` extension method. There is no `AppBuilder` type there and so on, and there are no `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin.Cors` packages or similar. So you have to either implement all that yourself (no reason to, because you can use the same functionality provided by asp.net core framework) or wait for OWIN packages that target .NET Standard\Core and do that (didn't check, maybe they even exist already).

So, your code uses packages which are indeed not compatible with your target framework, as exception you have at runtime shows. So another answer (for some reason downvoted) is technically correct.

If you still want to use those packages reliably - you need to target full .NET Framework and not .NET Core. To do that, open your .csproj file and change

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
```

To some .NET framework version that supports .NET Standard 2.0, for example:

```
<TargetFramework>net47</TargetFramework>
```

Then go to nuget package manager and, if you have `microsoft.aspnetcore.all` package (or other packages targeting .NET Core) - uninstall it, you don't need it anyway. Then install `Microsoft.AspNetCore` package and all other asp.net core packages you need (if not installed already). Rebuild, run and it will work just fine.

That works because all (most?) AspNetCore packages target .NET Standard, not .NET Core, and you can use them in projects targeting full .NET Framework.

Note that by doing that you have asp.net Core project, but not on .NET Core, with all consequences that come from that (cannot run with `dotnet run`, on linux need to run with mono, and so on).

Comment: Exactly what i found out aswell.

Answer (score -2):

The Microsoft.Owin components will not work on dotnet core 2.0, they only work on .NET 4.5+

Comment: I am sure you are wrong here ! Have you checked two examples i posted with my question? Those examples were all about using 'IAppBuilder' with 'IApplcationBuilder'. Please read them first. And also how about this official guideline from Microsoft talking about using Owin for .net core app. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/owin

Comment: A lot of the confusion here is that Asp.Net Core can run on .Net and .Net Core. That first example is using Asp.Net Core on .Net.